# Sorting Lists of tuples based on a list of tuples - Python

Tags: python, sorting, tuples

I am trying to sort a list of tuples based on another list of tuples by a key in that list.

Say I have the following:

```
list1 = [(5, 'something'),(2,'bobby'),(9,'suzy'),(6,'crab')]
list2 = [('something','othervalues'),('suzy','stuff'),('bobby','otherthings')]
```

And from this I would receive the output soring on the first element of each tuple in list1.

```
sorted = [('suzy','stuff'),('something','othervalues'),('bobby','otherthings') ]
```

So essentially it performs an intersection and then sorts on the remaining values by the first element in the tuple of list1.

I am not sure how to go about this, so any help would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do what the description says, sort a list of tuples based on another list of tuples by a key in that list:

```
rank = {key:rank for rank, key in list1}
print(sorted(list2, key=lambda t: rank.get(t[0]), reverse=True))
```

Answer (score 3):

First create a dictionary from `list1`:

```
>>> order = dict(reversed(t) for t in list1)
```

This creates a `name -> number` mapping.

Then you can use the `sorted` method (don't name your variable this way) and a `lambda` expression as `key`:

```
>>> sorted(list2, key=lambda x: order[x[0]], reverse=True)
[('suzy', 'stuff'), ('something', 'othervalues'), ('bobby', 'otherthings')]
```

or, if you want to sort in-place:

```
>>> list2.sort(key=lambda x: order[x[0]], reverse=True)
```

---

Worth reading: [**Sorting Mini-HOW TO**](http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting)

Answer (score 0):

This would be easy were `list2` a [`dict`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict), like this:

```
{'bobby': 'otherthings', 'something': 'othervalues', 'suzy': 'stuff'}
```

Python will do the conversion for you:

```
>>> dict2 = dict(list2)
```

Then you can use a [`list comprehension`](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> [(k,dict2[k]) for _,k in sorted(list1, reverse=True) if k in dict2]
[('suzy', 'stuff'), ('something', 'othervalues'), ('bobby', 'otherthings')]
```

**N.B:** [`sorted`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sorted) is a built-in Python function and a bad choice for a variable name.